How to find out if a style has a dark mode
Now that in Qt 6.8 the ColorScheme has become writable, I'd like to implement a dark/light switch.
My app also allows users to choose the style, and there is at least one style that doesn't have a dark mode (windowsvista). So when a style doesn't have a dark mode I'd like to disable the dark/light switch.
Is it possible to programmatically find out if a style has a switchable colorscheme?
If this is not possible, hardcoding the style names is probably the best option. Are there styles for linux and MAC that aren't switchable? I can only test Windows.

I'm afraid that, at least right now, there's not a proper and reliable way to detect that. Not only Qt doesn't currently provide any way to detect that, but, as far as I understand, there's no common and cross platform way to define it: there is no convention about cross platform styles (especially on Linux), therefore Qt cannot provide any information about such aspects. The only thing you could do is to provide a customizable setting that allows the user to choose what to do, and assume a default behavior.

I've asked people on linux and MAC to test the styles that were available to them, and all of them followed the system light/dark setting. So I think it's safe to say that only 'windowsvista' is always light. So I'll just do something like switch.setDisabled(style.name() == 'windowsvista')

Note that that would obviously only valid for win/mac, on Linux things are rather more complicated, including the fact that some styles have peculiar behavior and may be controlled by system configuration (specifically, KDE styles). The only thing I can think of is to briefly toggle the light/dark mode (checking the app palette for both), then restore the previous state.
